# Adding values ​in a column of another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes, the first with `id` and `cnpj` field and the second with just `cnpj`. This second dataframe can have new values ​​in the `cnpj` column so I need to create a new dataframe with the cpfs that it doesn't have in the first dataframe and add +1 to the id after the maximum value.

How can I do this?

Dataframe 1:

| id | cnpj |
| --- | --- |
| 11 | 552030405560 |
| 12 | 709050358572 |
| 13 | 999680558533 |
| 14 | 585680558542 |

Dataframe 2:

| cnpj |
| --- |
| 552030405560 |
| 709050358572 |
| 999680558533 |
| 585680558542 |
| 658540805552 |
| 498546543258 |

Expected output:

| id | cnpj |
| --- | --- |
| 11 | 552030405560 |
| 12 | 709050358572 |
| 13 | 999680558533 |
| 14 | 585680558542 |
| 15 | 658540805552 |
| 16 | 498546543258 |

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can use `merge` and fill with a custom function:

```
def fillmax(s):
    MAX = s.max()
    mask = s.isna()
    return s.fillna(MAX+mask.cumsum().where(mask, 0)).convert_dtypes()


out = (df1
 .merge(df2, on='cnpj', how='right')
 .assign(id=lambda d: fillmax(d['id']))
)
```

output:

```
01

   id          cnpj
0  11  552030405560
1  12  709050358572
2  13  999680558533
3  14  585680558542
4  15  658540805552
5  16  498546543258
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do a merge and add it to the index

```
df_final = pd.merge(df2, df1, how = 'left').reset_index()
df_final['index'] = df_final['index'].add(df_final.iloc[0]['id']).astype(int)
df_final
```

Answer (score 0):

You could right merge on `cnpj` and then fill the null values ias needed:

```
merged = df1.merge(df2, how="right")
merged["id"] = merged["id"].where(merged["id"].notnull(), merged["id"].isnull().cumsum().add(merged["id"].max()))

>>> merged
     id          cnpj
0  11.0  552030405560
1  12.0  709050358572
2  13.0  999680558533
3  14.0  585680558542
4  15.0  658540805552
5  16.0  498546543258
```